# How to compute rising / setting times for stars and deep sky objects with Skyfield?

Tags: python, skyfield

I'm trying to compute rising and settings times for various objects with the [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) library. While the task is quite easy and well documented for planets (using the `almanac.rising_and_setting` function), it is not too clear to me how to do this with Stars and Deep Sky Objects.

Btw, how do I load NGC catalogues?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but start with [.starlib.Star()](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api.html#stars-and-other-distant-objects) and use [.almanac.risings_and_settings()](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-almanac.html#skyfield.almanac.risings_and_settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the RA and declination coordinates for any object, whether for a star or anything else, you can create a Skyfield `Star` that represents its position in the heavens:

https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/stars.html#building-a-single-star-from-its-coordinates

You can then pass that object — `barnard` in the example code at the above link — to `almanac.rising_and_setting()` exactly as you would pass a planet. The code would look like the example here:

https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/almanac.html#risings-and-settings

— except that your call would look like:

```
f = almanac.risings_and_settings(eph, barnard, bluffton)
```

There is not currently a way to load the NGC catalogs — I’ve never actually taken a look at how they are formatted online, nor have I seen a Skyfield contributor offer anything yet. If you have a link to your favorite online source for the NGC catalog, though, we could take a look? Open an issue if you find an online NGC catalog and think that Skyfield should learn to read it.